# Appending associative arrays in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I've been all over looking for a solution to this recently, and so far to no avail. I'm coming from php to python, and running into an associative array difference I'm not sure now to overcome.

Take this line:

```
data[user]={i:{'item':row[0],'time':row[1]}}
```

This overwrites each of my `data[user]` entries, obviously, as it's not appending, it's just replacing the data each time.

In php if I wanted to append a new bit of data in a for loop, I could do

```
data[user][i][]=array('item'=>'x','time'=>'y'); // crude example
```

In python, I can't do:

```
data[user][]={i:{'item':row[0],'time':row[1]}}
```

It barfs on my `[]`

I also can't do:

```
data[user][i]={'item':row[0],'time':row[1]}
```

where I is my iterator through the loop... and I think it's because the `data[user]` hasn't been defined, yet, as of the operating? I've created the `data={}`, but I don't have it populated with the users as keys, yet.

In python, do I have to have a key defined before I can define it including a sub-key?

I've tried a bunch of `.append()` options, and other weird tricks, but I want to know the *correct* method of doing this.

I *can* do:

```
data[user,i]={'item':row[0],'time':row[1]}
```

but this isn't what I want.

What's my proper method here, python friends?

Comment: Alright, it seems I haven't been as clear as I'd hoped. The issue isn't adding data[user]=stuff. The issue is adding data[user][i]=stuff

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should work.  Note that unlike PHP, Python has separate primitive types for numeric arrays (called "lists") and associative arrays (called "dictionaries" or "dicts").

```
if user not in data:
    data[user] = []
data[user].append({'item': row[0], 'time': row[1]})
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The syntax for:
.append({}) <-- didn't realize I could put my curly braces inside of the append. Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Except don't call a list an "array" because there is also `array.array`.

Comment: @Wooble good point, corrected.  I haven't yet needed that one so I forget it exists.

Answer (score 4):

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for user,row,time in input:
    data[user].append({'row':row, 'time':time})
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is the way to go if you can use it.  I didn't use it because the OP might be in a situation where they can't (for instance, if `data` is being provided by some other library module)

Comment: @Zack you can use defaultdict with any class as long as it can be instantiated with 0 arguments, and even if not, you can use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) to provide the instantiation arguments beforehand. Silly example: `defaultdict(partial(raw_input, "initial_string? "))`

Comment: @lazyr I think you misunderstand - imagine that *the construction of the object stored in the variable `data`* is not under the control of the OP, so they're stuck with whatever type it has.  For instance, what if `data = shelve.open(...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [setdefault()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and do something like:

```
userData = data.setdefault(user, {})
userData[i] = {'item': row[0], 'time': row[1]}
```

Comment: also interesting. Thank you. =D

Answer (score 0):

If `data[user]` is a list, you can append to it with `data[user].append({'item':row[0],'time':row[1]})`.